# No module named "pyautogui" after using pip install and it appearing on pip freeze

Tags: python, module, pip, pyautogui

I have looked at other similar questions but I got no answer.
I have installed pyautogui through pip install and I have checked using pip freeze and when I try to import this module I get the error "No module named 'pyautogui'".
I have also tried to restart the IDE that I am using (Pycharm) and I still don't know what is going on.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the same python installation to run pip and to run your program?

Comment: @Sören I am new to programming, could you please explain what that means?

Comment: Well, do you have multiple python installations? Look around in `/usr`, `/usr/local`, `/opt`, ...

Try using `python -m pip` instead of just `pip`, so you can be sure which python installation you're running pip in.

Try running your program from the command line, just to remove your IDE as a source of error.

Comment: Oh, and post (=edit into your post!) the output of `type python` and `type pip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before doing anything else, try restarting your IDE. Sometimes it's as simple as the module wasn't available when it started up.

Otherwise, it is possible that your `pip` installation is running under a different version of python than the IDE you are using. Some computers come with python pre-installed, and some IDEs might install a new version as a dependency, so you can end up with two (or more) different copies of python.

The easiest solution is probably going to be to install the package from within Pycharm, which will use the same copy of python: [https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tips/install-and-import/#:~:text=PyCharm%20can%20do%20both.,according%20to%20your%20project%20styles](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tips/install-and-import/#:%7E:text=PyCharm%20can%20do%20both.,according%20to%20your%20project%20styles).

Alternatively, you can try opening the python interpreter and importing the module there:

```sh
$ python
```

```py
>>> import pyautogui
```

If that also fails, then installing `pyautogui` in the shell by running:

```sh
$ python -m pip install pyautogui
```

might solve it, if your IDE uses the same installation that is on your `$PATH`, but not the same as `pip`.

If that doesn't work, then you're going to need to figure out which python installations are being used where.

Comment: When I tried running "$ python", I got the error '$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: The `$` is to symbolize your shell prompt.

Comment: @Sören What is the shell prompt. Is it cmd?

Comment: Also, when I tried installing it using the link you sent it didn't work

Comment: @Sören i was actually running the anaconda in Pycharm, does this have any effect?

Comment: @Sören I changed it to the normal Python instead of the anaconda and then tried installing it using the link sent and then it worked. Thank you!